# Using Query randomly

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Hello I m developing a basic project that resemble vocabulary card.I am adding some english words and turkish meaning in database also,I get only "word" data from db. I want to get its id and turkish meaning.How can i do that ? Also, 
I do not know other nulls in query's bracket.How can I get the information for that.

this is db code :

```
public class DataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DBWORDS";
private static final String TABLE_NAME  = "WTABLE";
private static final String ID  ="ID";
private static final String WORD   = "WORD";
private static final String WORD_TR1 = "TURKCE_1";


public DataBase(Context context){
    super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public DataBase(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_DBTABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +WORD+
            " TEXT," +WORD_TR1+" TEXT" + "  )";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_DBTABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    String TABLE_DELETE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME ;
    db.execSQL(TABLE_DELETE);
    onCreate(db);

}

public long addRecord(Words words){
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(WORD,words.getWORD());
    contentValues.put(WORD_TR1,words.getTR1());
    long status = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    sqLiteDatabase.close();
    return status;
}
public List<Words> allRecords(){
    List<Words> wordsList = new ArrayList<>();
    String sql_query = "SELECT *FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase =this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor =sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(sql_query,null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        Words words =null;
        do{
            words = new Words();
            words.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
            words.setWORD(cursor.getString(1));
            words.setTR1(cursor.getString(2));
            wordsList.add(words);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return wordsList;
}

public String getRandomQuote(){
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1",new String[]
            {WORD},null,null,null,null,null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        return cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(WORD));
    }
    else
        return "nothing";
}
```

main activity :

```
 btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),WordsActivity.class);
            DataBase dataBase = new DataBase(getApplicationContext());
           String random =  dataBase.getRandomQuote();
            intent.putExtra("random",random);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

words activity :

```
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        Intent intent= getIntent();
        String random =intent.getStringExtra("random");
         textView.setText("Number : "+ random);
```

After that I got  "Hello" in text.
I want to  "Hello" "Merhaba" "21".

Comment: part of 

 Intent intent= getIntent();
    String random =intent.getStringExtra("random");

    textView.setText("Number : "+ random );
 is another activity.

Comment: Google **android SQlite query** comes up with first match of [SQLiteDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html). A **find** in this on **query** includes [query](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: How do you expect someone to come up with an answer considering that most, if any, do not have some magical power that tells us the schema/structure of the database/table(s)/column(s) where your data is held? I'd suggest editing your question to include all relevant information. All we know is that you have a column called WORD, you likely have a column that has a unique value since you mention id; at a guess and only a guess it could be _id. That's all you appeared to have said.

Comment: Mike thank you for your comment.Does it contain necessary information now?

Answer (score 0):

You are only getting WORD from the table in the query. You need to get **WORD_TR1** (assuming that's the translation) and **ID**. So you need to tell the query to return those columns as well. Then concatenate them to the string that is returned. All of this in the **`getRandomQuote`** method.

e.g.

```
public String getRandomQuote(){
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1",new String[]
            {WORD, WORD_TR1, ID},null,null,null,null,null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        return cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(WORD)) +
        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(WORD_TR1)) +
        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ID));
    }
    else
        return "nothing";
}
```

I think that's what you want (note not tested so might be some errors).